# Not able to run first spring program using XML configuration. I'm getting this error

Tags: java, xml, spring

> Error :  Exception in thread "main"
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException:
>   IOException parsing XML document from class path resource
>   [applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource
>   [applicationContext.xml] cannot be opened because it d

Code:

```
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
```

Comment: Hello Raj, it appears that the issue is likely application context can not be established.  Can you please post the code as well? Many things could cause this.

Comment: Are you using spring boot? Either way, make sure `applicationContext.xml` is under `src/main/resources` and you import it in a `@Configuration` file using `@ImportResource({"classpath*:applicationContext.xml"})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have the xml configuration file `applicationContext.xml` in your project resources path.

Answer (score 0):

ApplicationContext.xml file should be in classpath. Kindly keep applicationContext.xml in src as you are using ClassPathXmlApplicationContext class for loading applicationContext.xml file

hope it will be helpful to you